# 403:The request is understood, but it has been refused Twitter Android

Tags: android, android-twitter

I am trying to tweet on twitter from android. Now for this i have create an application on dev.twitter and downloaded sample code from [**this link**](http://chintankhetiya.wordpress.com/2013/07/18/sharing-text-image-in-twitter-android-example/) and update both keys with my app keys.

Now i run the code authenticate the account and after it i tweet and this tweet includes image and text both image was on URL as define in sample code. Now i first time it shows me image and text successfully uploaded but when i try to again tweet it gives me 403 status update error.

For this i change the text message "status Text" and image URL but still it is giving me "403 status"  update error. **I have the same code as written in sample code only keys are changed.**

Here is my Logcat:

```
10-04 11:26:25.015: W/System.err(22822): 403:The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits (https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following).
10-04 11:26:25.015: W/System.err(22822): message - Error creating status.
10-04 11:26:25.015: W/System.err(22822): code - 189
10-04 11:26:25.025: W/System.err(22822): Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
10-04 11:26:25.025: W/System.err(22822):    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=b2b52c28 or
10-04 11:26:25.025: W/System.err(22822):    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=11331d43
10-04 11:26:25.025: W/System.err(22822): TwitterException{exceptionCode=[b2b52c28-11331d43], statusCode=403, message=Error creating status., code=189, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.3}
10-04 11:26:25.025: W/System.err(22822):    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:177)
10-04 11:26:25.025: W/System.err(22822):    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:61)
10-04 11:26:25.025: W/System.err(22822):    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.post(HttpClientWrapper.java:98)
10-04 11:26:25.030: W/System.err(22822):    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.post(TwitterImpl.java:1871)
10-04 11:26:25.030: W/System.err(22822):    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.updateStatus(TwitterImpl.java:252)
10-04 11:26:25.030: W/System.err(22822):    at chintan.khetiya.android.Twitter_code.Twitt_Sharing.Share_Pic_Text_Titter(Twitt_Sharing.java:126)
10-04 11:26:25.030: W/System.err(22822):    at chintan.khetiya.android.Twitter_code.Twitt_Sharing$PostTwittTask.doInBackground(Twitt_Sharing.java:91)
10-04 11:26:25.030: W/System.err(22822):    at chintan.khetiya.android.Twitter_code.Twitt_Sharing$PostTwittTask.doInBackground(Twitt_Sharing.java:1)
10-04 11:26:25.030: W/System.err(22822):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-04 11:26:25.035: W/System.err(22822):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
10-04 11:26:25.035: W/System.err(22822):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-04 11:26:25.040: W/System.err(22822):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
10-04 11:26:25.040: W/System.err(22822):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
10-04 11:26:25.040: W/System.err(22822):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Seems like you have reached limits... thats what this log saying

Comment: @Pratik i have tweet only one time and tried next time. Even as mentioned on sites that 1000 tweets are allowed

Comment: try this link http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-send-image-to-twitpic-from-android/

Comment: api use in this project no longer supported

Comment: api use in this project no longer supported and it requires api v 1.1 at that time api v 3 is in use

Comment: @User42590 the code works perfectly for me. Only I had to reset my emulator time as it was showing wrong one. Check this out..

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I had this same error and upgrading to the latest version of twitter4j 3.0.5 (at the time of this writing) fixed the issue.

Get the latest here http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html#download

EDIT:  I should mention that the version i was running was twitter4j 3.0.3.  So by going to version 3.0.5 or 3.0.6 fixed the issue for me.

Comment: great this is perfect solution

Comment: Thanks. ran into the same issue and updating the lib helped. Dont know the reason for issue in the 3.0.3 version though.

Comment: @erdomester Hi my friend. I have the same issue on 4.0.1. I'm using twitter4j within this library. https://github.com/antonkrasov/AndroidSocialNetworks Can you share me if you could fix it.

Comment: as I'm using twitter4j-core-4.0.4-javadoc.jar in my eclipse i won't accepting

Answer (score 0):

in

ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();

add 
cb.setUseSSL(true)

it will work

redirect url ssl required make sure your application running on https.

Comment: for authentication you would have create ConfigurationBuilder object there you should add  cb.setUseSSL(true)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when I wanted to share an image with a wrong a url. Turned out I set the wrong folder in the url, Twitter didn't find the image thus throw an error. Question is, why do they show this error instead of something like "wrong url".

You may also run into this error when your are trying to post a longer text. I ran into this when I wanted to share a text (124 characters) and a link (10) characters and it didn't let me post it.

Answer (score 0):

Found this problem again in the non-stable version 4.0.6.

Try not using maven in the way is specified in twitteer4j's website, which is this:

```
 <dependencies>
      <dependency>
           <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
           <version>[4.0,)</version>
       </dependency>
       ...
   </dependencies>
```

Instead, put an specific version (current stable is 4.0.4 and fix this problem, but [4.0,) gets the newest from 4.0, so 4.0.6)

```
 <dependencies>
      <dependency>
           <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
           <version>4.0.4</version>
       </dependency>
       ...
   </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have `403:The request is understood, but it has been refused` you also have error code that explain what exactly was wrong. It helped me understand the reason.

Explanation for error codes you can see here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/support/twitter-api/error-troubleshooting